# Issues with Git clone over HTTP and SSL verification

Tags: git, http, authentication, ssl, github

I'm having issues with accessing repository on Stash on a private server.  When doing the following clone command, the repository is not able to authenticate and connect to the site.

```
git clone https://username@server.com:usr/projects/testproject/project.git
```

The command is timing out and is not authenticating with my web server.  I've tried the following code globally to help bypass the SSL verification which I've found is likely the issue, but it's not working.

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

**Doing this to try bypassing the SSL verification but am still not able to connect.**  If I go to my browser and type in the URL, it authenticates automatically for me and I'm able to access the repo.  The issue is that many of my users will only be doing this through the terminal command line.  Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is not a valid URL. Do you mean `git clone https://username@server.com:server.com/usr/projects/testproject/project.git` ?

Comment: This was just a test example for posting.  I'm not able to post the actual username and project directory.  The issue still stands though.  Wondering if there are any other solutions other than git config --global http.sslVerify false

Comment: u need to add sha permission into ur server setting or clone https url not .git url

Comment: Regaridn the url, you would need `server.com/usr`, not `server.com:usr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently went into same issue and found this:
Check this out: http://blog.vogella.com/2010/08/09/git-https/

However a piece of advice (i learnt it the hard way): Try not to use the dumb protocols as much you can avoid them. Setting up repos over SSH was a great help and it saved a lotta pain. You could look into it as well.

Hope it helps!